# Network-Manager automatically disconnects after 20 seconds

Tags: linux, networkmanager

I have a Quectel EG25-G setup but whenever I connect (right after a reboot) it connects for 20 seconds and then disconnects.
It happens at the

```
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4569] device (ttyUSB2): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'modem-no-carrier', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046772.4677] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: failed for connection 'telstra'
```

point but I can't read why this is happening.

Can someone point me in the right direction please ?

configuration:

```
nvidia@localhost:~$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/telstra
[sudo] password for nvidia:
[connection]
id=telstra
uuid=9ae31580-093b-45ec-8b8c-3c22e7eca76f
type=gsm
permissions=
[gsm]
apn=telstra.internet
number=*99#
password-flags=1
[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

output of NetworkManager and ping google.com :

```
nvidia@localhost:~$ journalctl -u NetworkManager -f &
[1] 7916
nvidia@localhost:~$ ping google.com &-- Logs begin at Fri 2022-06-24 04:58:32 UTC. --
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0549] device (l4tbr0): Activation: starting connection 'l4tbr0' (73df77e3-1d83-4794-afcb-e6079b37272b)
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0575] device (l4tbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0602] device (l4tbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0609] device (l4tbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0612] device (l4tbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0628] device (l4tbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0636] device (l4tbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:58:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046719.0681] device (l4tbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 24 04:58:41 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046721.6864] manager: startup complete
Jun 24 04:58:43 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046723.1537] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
[2] 7917
nvidia@localhost:~$ ping: google.com: Name or service not known
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.7954] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'disabled' --> 'enabling' (reason: user preference)
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.7970] manager: (ttyUSB2): new Broadband device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.7976] device (ttyUSB2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.7983] device (ttyUSB2): modem state 'enabling'
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.7997] device (ttyUSB2): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.8004] policy: auto-activating connection 'telstra'
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.8025] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: starting connection 'telstra' (9ae31580-093b-45ec-8b8c-3c22e7eca76f)
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.8030] device (ttyUSB2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046741.8032] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.5602] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'enabling' --> 'enabled' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.6982] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'enabled' --> 'registered' (reason: unknown)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.7381] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8055] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'connected' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046742.8173] device (ttyUSB2): ip-ifname: set ifname 'ttyUSB2', unknown ifindex
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8177] device (ttyUSB2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8183] device (ttyUSB2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046742.8190] device (ttyUSB2): interface ttyUSB2 not up for IP configuration
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8191] modem["ttyUSB2"]: using modem-specified IP timeout: 20 seconds
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8253] loaded PPP plugin /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-ppp-plugin.so
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8264] ppp-manager: starting PPP connection
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8317] ppp-manager: pppd started with pid 7929
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (plugin_init): initializing
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 3 / phase 'serial connection'
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8628] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 6 / phase 'authenticate'
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): passwd-hook, requesting credentials...
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): got credentials from NetworkManager
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 8 / phase 'network'
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8875] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.8875] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: local IP address 10.247.106.201
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: local IP address 10.247.106.201
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: primary DNS address 101.168.244.101
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: secondary DNS address 101.168.244.103
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 9 / phase 'running'
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_ip_up): ip-up event
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: primary DNS address 101.168.244.101
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_ip_up): sending IPv4 config to NetworkManager...
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain pppd[7929]: secondary DNS address 101.168.244.103
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9212] ppp-manager: (IPv4 Config Get) reply received.
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9268] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9297] device (ttyUSB2): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9341] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9350] device (ttyUSB2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9356] device (ttyUSB2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9359] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9387] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9391] policy: set 'telstra' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 24 04:59:02 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046742.9437] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 24 04:59:03 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046743.1280] policy: set-hostname: set hostname to 'linux' (from address lookup)
Jun 24 04:59:03 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046743.9009] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 24 04:59:05 linux pppd[7929]: sif6addr: ioctl(SIOCSIFADDR): Permission denied (line 2613)
Jun 24 04:59:05 linux NetworkManager[5093]: sif6addr: ioctl(SIOCSIFADDR): Permission denied (line 2613)
Jun 24 04:59:05 linux NetworkManager[5093]: cif6addr: ioctl(SIOCDIFADDR): No such address
Jun 24 04:59:05 linux pppd[7929]: cif6addr: ioctl(SIOCDIFADDR): No such address
[2]+ Exit 2 ping google.com
nvidia@localhost:~$
nvidia@localhost:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.24.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=34.7 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=74.3 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=71.4 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=55.9 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=54.4 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=52.7 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=51.7 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s23-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.24.46): icmp_seq=8 ttl=115 time=52.0 ms
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4567] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4569] device (ttyUSB2): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'modem-no-carrier', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046772.4677] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: failed for connection 'telstra'
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4690] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4711] device (ttyUSB2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4955] policy: set-hostname: set hostname to 'localhost.localdomain' (no default device)
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4965] device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 24 04:59:32 linux NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.4985] policy: auto-activating connection 'telstra'
Jun 24 04:59:32 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.5016] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: starting connection 'telstra' (9ae31580-093b-45ec-8b8c-3c22e7eca76f)
Jun 24 04:59:32 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.5035] device (ttyUSB2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:32 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.5038] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 24 04:59:32 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046772.5361] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046779.6407] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:39 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046779.6622] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046786.7669] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:46 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046786.7880] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.8956] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046793.8960] modem-broadband[ttyUSB2]: failed to connect modem: Sending command failed: 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.8962] device (ttyUSB2): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.8971] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <warn> [1656046793.8988] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: failed for connection 'telstra'
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9007] device (ttyUSB2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9028] policy: auto-activating connection 'telstra'
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9052] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: starting connection 'telstra' (9ae31580-093b-45ec-8b8c-3c22e7eca76f)
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9064] device (ttyUSB2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9072] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 24 04:59:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046793.9246] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 05:00:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046801.0289] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'connecting' --> 'registered' (reason: user-requested)
Jun 24 05:00:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[5093]: <info> [1656046801.0454] modem["ttyUSB2"]: modem state changed, 'registered' --> 'connecting' (reason: user-requested)
```

... etc...

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. Did you mean to post this on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com)?

Comment: i didn't even know about Serverfault..but now i do.. yes.. yes i do, thank you !
am i able to delete this ? or can you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

seeing i can't delete this and i've found the answer:

Someone here suggested to update to the latest ModemManager like:
Code:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common # contains add-apt-repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aleksander-m/modemmanager-bionic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install modemmanager libqmi-utils libmbim-utils policykit-1
sudo reboot
```

and it all started working. Must have been a a ModemHandler bug in the older verision of ModemManager that the base image of NVidia comes with.